# Create multiple document from each group in illustrator useing javascript

Tags: adobe-illustrator, javascript

I have Ai file whitch file have many groups each group different design. How can I create javascript to separate each group to file. Or any options to do this and each file have to be same name as group name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea about javascript

Comment: This isn't a "write a script for me" web site. We hare here to *help* not complete tasks upon demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var groups = activeDocument.activeLayer.groupItems;
for (var i=0; i<groups.length; i++) {
  var newDoc = documents.add(DocumentColorSpace.RGB, activeDocument.width, activeDocument.height);
  var newLayer = newDoc.layers[0];
  var newGroup = groups[i].duplicate();
  newGroup.move(newLayer, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
  var newFile = new File("~/Desktop/" + groups[i].name + ".ai");
  newDoc.saveAs(newFile);
}
```

Comment: Error 24: copy.move is not a function.

Comment: I wrote that code without testing it, just to show you the gist. It turns out "copy" was a bad choice of variable name. Also, creating a new layer was unnecessary, and saveAs takes a File rather than a path. I have modified the code, and tested it. It is fully working.

Comment: Thank you so much Byron.

Comment: Can you upvote my answer and mark it as Accepted?